# webpack -- how to include nodejs module for js/jsx in non-current directory

Tags: node.js, webpack

Trying to include a npm module in my jsx.

My dir structure is something like:

```
   app/
     node_modules/
     webpack.config.json
     package.json
     main.js

   react/
     myreact1.jsx
     myreact2.jsx
```

Note: purposely do not want a package.json & node_modules in react/

I've figured out that I have to do this for webpack2 config:

```
   resolve: {
     modules: ["node_modules", path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
   }
```

This forces webpack to first always try ./node_modules, then default to app/node_modules

However, for the module I'm trying to include in myreact.jsx (npm: "request"), this module uses alot of native node libraries like "fs" and "tls", etc.

webpack now gives me this error:

Abbreviated error:

```
ERROR in ./~/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/myproj/app/node_modules/request/lib'
 @ ./~/request/lib/har.js 3:9-22
 @ ./~/request/request.js
 @ ./~/request/index.js
 @ ../react/myreact1.jsx
 @ ./app.jsx
 @ ./main.js
```

Display-error-details version of the error:

```
ERROR in ./~/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/myproj/app/node_modules/request/lib'
resolve 'fs' in '/myproj/app/node_modules/request/lib'
```

How do I get webpack to correctly find the native node modules 'fs', 'tls', 'net' etc for 'request' module and the other 3rd party modules it uses inside it's own node_modules?

Thanks for any help

Comment: why are you trying to use `request` on your front end code? you have literally dozens of libs to choose from that do that everything request does but for client side code, include `fetch` which is not even a library, but is implemented natively by browsers

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't webpack be able to do this?  I thought it could package nodejs-dependent backend modules as well, for the front-end?  Can't browserify do this? (and webpack can match browserify on features.. ?)

Comment: What would `fs` do on the client side? some code runs only on a server regardless of it being a node module

Comment: That's a good point. I was so bent on getting it to work, that I lost sight of the forest for the trees. However, to play devil's advocate, wouldn't that be the case for most node libraries built-in?  And wouldn't that pretty much invalidate 99% of npm nodejs packages, for use on the browser?  So what's the point of webpack and browserify saying that they can package back-end nodejs npm modules for the front-end, if they can't actually do it for 99% of the node modules out there, that most likely use basic stuff like 'fs' (or have dependencies that use 'fs')...???

Comment: You're confusing built in nodejs modules with packages on NPM, which include tens of thousands of 100% client side code like React, jQuery etc

Comment: If you were doing it without a module bundler you would need to add script tags or concatenate your vendor libs. but nowadays all of these libs are also available on npm and exported as a node module, but they don't require any of the server side modules that come built in with nodejs

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for the suggestions!   I guess there's no quick way to see if an npm module has nodejs backend dependencies (such as 'fs' or 'net') other than scouring the dependencies tree? (Or unless the author himself states so, such as for 'browser-request').